# "play test" classpath differs from "sbt test" classpath

Tags: junit, playframework, jenkins, playframework-2.0, sbt

Situation: 
I want to execute JUnit test cases for my Play! 2.0 application on a Jenkins Server.
To build and test my app on the server I want to use SBT (with command sequence: `clean compile test`).

Problem: 
Regardless of Jenkins, the command `play test` uses a different classpath than the command `java -jar "sbt-launch.jar" test` (both commands executed in the root directory of my play project, both commands use the same sbt version 0.12.2). My test cases can be compiled with `play test` but with `java -jar "sbt-launch.jar" test` the compiler complains that some JUnit classes (e.g., `org.junit.rules.TestWatcher`) are missing.

Analysis:
The command `show test:full-classpath` reveals that the classpathes indeed differ:

`play test` classpath contains: `Attributed(<playhome>\repository\local\junit\junit-dep\4.10\jars\junit-dep.jar)`

`java -jar "sbt-launch.jar test` classpath contains: `Attributed(<userhome>\.ivy2\cache\junit\junit-dep\jars\junit-dep-4.8.2.jar)`

Question: 
Any ideas how to ensure that `java -jar "sbt-launch.jar test` uses the same classpath as `play test`?

Build.scala:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

val appName         = "my app"
val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Play framework dependencies
    javaCore, javaJdbc, javaEbean,
    // Add your project dependencies here
    "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.1.0",
    "com.feth" %% "play-authenticate" % "0.2.5-SNAPSHOT",
    "org.mongodb" % "mongo-java-driver" % "2.10.1",
    "com.embedly" % "embedly-api" % "0.1.5",
    "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.9.5",
    "org.mongojack" % "mongojack" % "2.0.0-RC5",
    "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.3"
)

val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    resolvers += Resolver.url("play-easymail (release)", url("http://joscha.github.com/play-easymail/repo/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
    resolvers += Resolver.url("play-easymail (snapshot)", url("http://joscha.github.com/play-easymail/repo/snapshots/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),

    resolvers += Resolver.url("play-authenticate (release)", url("http://joscha.github.com/play-authenticate/repo/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
    resolvers += Resolver.url("play-authenticate (snapshot)", url("http://joscha.github.com/play-authenticate/repo/snapshots/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
)
}
```

Comment: could you provide your `build.sbt` or `Build.scala`? Do you have any junit dependency in there?

Comment: Sure, pasted it above. One of these dependencies requires JUnit 4.8.2. However, with `play test` JUnit 4.10 takes precedence.

Answer (score 0):

The `play` script rewires sbt to use a local JUnit file repository in addition to any remote you've used. This is why the download is so large.  Ivy, by default, will not copy local files into its local cache, as it assumes they are stable.

SO, what you're seeing is the sbt script which downloaded the file vs. the Play script which has its own local repo that takes priority over the downloaded file.

Now the fun part is around versioning.  Ivy has interesting version conflict resolution.

If you paste you look in your `target/resolution-cache/reports` directory, you may get some insight into the difference between the two commands and why the one junit is chosen over another.  My guess is there's a dynamic version range which is looking in the local repository for the play script and not finding the newer version of junit-dep.